# How to Fingerprint a JWK?

Tags: ecdsa, rsa-key-fingerprint, jwk

Is there a standard, canonical method for creating a fingerprint (aka thumbprint) for a JWK?

From what I was reading it seems that the standard doesn't define how a `kid` should be specified, which I find odd. To me it makes the most since to have it be a deterministic value rather than one that requires a lookup table such that others could easily recreate the key id in by virtue of possessing the public key.

I am aware that SSH fingerprints and X.509 thumbprints are standardized, but those don't seem like a suitable solution for all environments where JWKs are used (especially browsers) because they are too complex for naive implementations and including the libraries capable of manipulating such (i.e. forge) would waste a lot of memory, bandwidth, and vm compile time.

### Update

Officially it's called a "thumbprint" not a "fingerprint".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the [RFC7638](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7638) will answer your question.

This RFC describes a way to compute a hash value over a JWK.

It is really easy to implement:

- Keep the required parameters only. For a RSA key: `kty`, `n` and `e` and for an EC key: `crv`, `kty`, `x` and `y`.
- Sort those parameters in lexicographic order: `e`,`kty` and `n`
- Compute the parameters and values into Json: `{"e":"AQAB","kty":"RSA","n":"0vx7agoebGcQSuuPiLJXZptN9nndrQmbXEps2 aiAFbWhM78LhWx4cbbfAAtVT86zwu1RK7aPFFxuhDR1L6tSoc_BJECPebWKRXjBZCi FV4n3oknjhMstn64tZ_2W-5JsGY4Hc5n9yBXArwl93lqt7_RN5w6Cf0h4QyQ5v-65Y GjQR0_FDW2QvzqY368QQMicAtaSqzs8KJZgnYb9c7d0zgdAZHzu6qMQvRL5hajrn1n 91CbOpbISD08qNLyrdkt-bFTWhAI4vMQFh6WeZu0fM4lFd2NcRwr3XPksINHaQ-G_x BniIqbw0Ls1jF44-csFCur-kEgU8awapJzKnqDKgw"}`
- Hash it using SHA-256 and encode it into Base64 Url Safe: `NzbLsXh8uDCcd-6MNwXF4W_7noWXFZAfHkxZsRGC9Xs`

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a true standard, but this topic has been discussed in the [IETF mailing archives](https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/jose/current/msg01577.html). While the conversation seemed to get a little side-tracked by whether or not canonical JSON was a good idea in general, there was one method that seems reasonable as a standard fingerprinting method.

1. Remove all "metadata" fields from the JWK (where in this case "metadata" is defined as any non-required key, ie anything but "kty" and the parameters for the encryption algorithm defined by the [JWA RFC-7518](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518.txt)).
2. Convert stripped JWK into "canonical" JSON (sort keys lexicographically, no leading or trailing whitespace, and no whitespace between tokens).
3. Compute digest over created JSON string.

There is also no true standard that I am aware of for canonical JSON, but all the sources I've seen agree on at least the rules listed above (which are the only rules that should be relevant for the types of objects used for JWK's).